# Is this an arithmetic sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

I came up with a question that made me think twice.
Study the sequence

$$
\sin(x_1), \sin(x_2), \sin(x_3),...
$$

where $x_1, x_2, x_3,...$ is chosen so

$d=\sin(x_{i+1})-\sin(x_i)$

is constant. Is this really an arithmetic sequence?

Comment: It is an arithmetic sequence because the difference between consecutive terms is constant. – What exactly are your doubts about it?

Comment: That is, by definition, an arithmetic sequence starting at $\sin(x_1)$ with step size $d$. What might be confusing is that no such sequences (that are arithmetic progressions) exist unless $d=0$. It might be a nice exercise for the poster to figure out why that is.

Comment: If they are chosen in a way such that it is a constant difference between consecutive terms then it indeed is an arithmetic sequence. What are the doubts??

Comment: @AnCar. It *does* exist if you allow for complex arguments $x_n$ :)

Comment: @MartinR hehe, true. But I don't think this is what the poster had in mind.

Comment: My first idea was that this might indeed by an arithmetic series, but as the values can't get higher than $1$ or lower than $-1$, the series must either be finite or the values need to be equal to zero.

Comment: @Dominique Precisly my thought. An arithmetic sequence values always tends to plus/minus infinity if d not equals zero! And therefor - either d=0 or it is finite?

Comment: I know that about sin (x) when x i complex and so forth but my student haven't read complex number yet. They do that next spring. So this time - x is real!